# Update category name is not updated in admin panel

Tags: magento2, category

Actually trying to update category name using category id its working internally when we debug the code but it is not updating in admin panel.

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        

$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

//var_dump($storeManager->getStore()->getData());
$storeId = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
echo $storeId."<br/ >";

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository')->create()->setStoreId($storeId)->load(44);
$category->setName('test1234');
$category->save(); 

echo $category->getName();
echo $category->getId();
```

Answer (score 3):

-> **You can set store id**

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
// require __DIR__ . '../../csv/Customer.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$category = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load(3);
$d["entity_id"] = "3";
$d["is_active"] = "1";

$d["name"] = "TESTA-2_ENG";

// $d["url_key"] = "testa-1-eng";
$d["store_id"] = "0";
$category->setData($d);
$category->save();
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface')->save($category);
```

Comment: I have set the storeId also, but still, in the admin area, the name is not updated. from backend controller, I am trying to update the name of the category

Comment: Please give your controller code I will check it.

Comment: While update, the updates are reflecting in front-end, and default store view, but in all store view, it's not getting an update. I tried with set store id. but still now the all store view value is not getting update

Answer (score 0):

```
$categoryTmp = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load( $magCatid);

// $category->setData($d);
    $categoryTmp->setName($cat['name']);
    $categoryTmp->setStoreId(0);

    $categoryTmp->setIsActive(true);
//  $categoryTmp->setUrlKey($cat['newSystemSlug']);
    $categoryTmp->setData('description', $cat['name']);
    // $categoryTmp->setData('cicategoryid', $cat['group_id']);
//  $categoryTmp->setPosition($cat['displayPosition']*100);
        $categoryTmp->save();
        $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface')->save($categoryTmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$obj->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode('frontend');
$storeManager = $obj->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categories = $categoryFactory->create();
$categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$categories->setStore(1);

foreach ($categories as $category)
{
    $category->setName('Test');
    $category->save();
}
```